# Calculating SHAP values with PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, shap

I'm looking for a way to reduce the computation time taken to calculate SHAP values on my large dataset (~180M rows, 6 features), and I came across this [article](https://databricks.com/blog/2022/02/02/scaling-shap-calculations-with-pyspark-and-pandas-udf.html) talking about using PySpark on SHAP.

I'm new to PySpark, and I'm trying to figure out how to run my code with the snippet provided in the article.

I'm running SHAP now with the code below, where `X_values` was also used to fit my Isolation Forest model.

```
X_values = X.values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_values)
```

Here's the snippet from the article.

```
def calculate_shap(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    for X in iterator:
        yield pd.DataFrame(
            explainer.shap_values(np.array(X), check_additivity=False)[0],
            columns=columns_for_shap_calculation,
        )

return_schema = StructType()
for feature in columns_for_shap_calculation:
    return_schema = return_schema.add(StructField(feature, FloatType()))

shap_values = df.mapInPandas(calculate_shap, schema=return_schema)
```

The article describes the snippet as follows.

> The code snippet demonstrates how to parallelize applying an
> Explainer with a Pandas UDF in PySpark. We define a pandas UDF called
> calculate_shap and then pass this function to mapInPandas. This method
> is then used to apply the parallelized method to the PySpark
> dataframe. We will use this UDF to run our SHAP performance tests.

I don't quite understand how the PySpark code works.

1. In the `calculate_shap` UDF, what is `X`? Is it my `X_values`, because I see `explainer.shap_values(np.array(X)...`, but `X` was not passed into `calculate_shap`?
2. The description mentioned "apply the parallelized method to the **PySpark dataframe**". Which one is the "PySpark dataframe"? Where did `df` come from?
3. Do I need to do any pre-processing or conversion from pandas dataframe to PySpark dataframe prior to running the snippet?

Comment: Yes to the 1st. As to the rest, they're trying to distribute SHAP calculations across cluster. If you need more, please [reprex].

Answer (score 1):

The code leverages the theoretical properties of Shapley's values to speed up the calculations. The idea is to separate the large spark df along rows and send the small batches to the worker nodes where Shap values are calculated (UDF), once this is finished the partial results are concatenated on the driver node. This can be done on a databricks or vanilla spark cluster.

To your questions:

1. X is the subset of rows from the original df
2. df is a spark dataframe
3. yes